# Automated lettrine and commands

Tags: macros, automation, lettrine

I need to automatically place lettrines on a text I don't want to edit directly.

So far I have been [using](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/224737/automating-lettrine)

```
\def\drop #1#2 {% note the space before {
  \lettrine{#1}{#2} % a trailing space
}
```

and

```
\drop Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec sagittis vitae massa nec gravida. Fusce quis porttitor leo.
```

The problem is that some paragraphs start with a command, e.g:

```
\marginnote{Foo} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec sagittis vitae massa nec gravida. Fusce quis porttitor leo.
```

In these cases various errors are returned; I have tried with `\expandafter` but with no luck.

How can I make Latex use the first "real" word for the lettrine, i.e. ignoring the (eventually) preceding command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach examines the catcode of the token following `\drop`.  If it is a command (catcode 0), it executes the 1st blob of tokens up to the first space and then reissues `\drop` again.  Therefore you can't accidentally leave spaces between arguments of a leading macro, e.g., `\rule{1ex}     {2ex}`, or the inter-space will scrog the argument absorption.  Generally, this is not an issue, and won't affect commands taking a single argument.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lettrine,marginnote}
\def\drop #1#2 {% note the space before {
  \ifcat\noexpand\relax\noexpand#1\def\next{#1{#2}\drop}\else
  \def\next{\lettrine{#1}{#2} }\fi% a trailing space
  \next
}
\begin{document}
\drop Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec sagittis vitae massa nec gravida. Fusce quis porttitor leo. 

The problem is that some paragraphs start with a command, e.g:

\drop \marginnote{Foo in the margin} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec sagittis vitae massa nec gravida. Fusce quis porttitor leo.
\end{document}
```

[image]